# Internet Explorer 9 & 10 Group Policy Preferences missing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, proxy, internet-explorer, group-policy

I have a single Domain Controller network (Windows Server 2008 R2, running on the 2003 Forest/domain level), with the clients currently migrating from WinXP Pro to Win7 Pro.

I Need to control the Proxy settings of Internet Explorer: I've built a policy that works fine on Windows XP + Internet Explorer 7 & 8, but not Windows 7 + Internet Explorer 10 & 11

That makes sense, as you have to [Set proxy using Policy Preferences instead of Admin Templates](https://web.archive.org/web/20140407055206/http://johnfail.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/configuring-internet-explorer-10s-proxy-via-group-policy/)

However, when I go to the Preferences, and try to select New, I only have 5 & 6, 7, and 8 selectable.

[image: IE 5-8]
<sub>(source: [technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-52-58/7558.gpp1.jpg))</sub>

I'd expect there to be IE9 and IE10 as well (I know [IE11 uses IE10 settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/how-to-configure-group-policy-preference-settings))

[image: IE 5-10]

I've tried applying the proxy settings using an IE8 policy, which works fine on the XP Clients, but not the 7 clients: The proxy settings are just empty.

I have a working Central ADMX Store (\[FQDN]\SYSVOL[FQDN]\Policies\PolicyDefinitions), to which I copied over the top first a set of Windows 2008 R2 + IE 10 policies, then a set of Windows 2012 R2 + IE 11 policies.

Just in case it was a local server issue, I backed up then copied over the 2012 R2 policies into the local server's c:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions, and run gpupdate /force.

I know the normal GPO section has worked because I have "At least Internet Explorer 11.0" settings in my central store (Such as "Allow Microsoft Services to provide enhanced Suggestions as the user types in the address bar"), but I still can't get 8 & 9/10 to show up in the preferences section.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to make these settings show up?

Comment: Is your second picture an actual screenshot or a mockup?

Comment: The second shot was found using a [Google image search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Internet+Explorer+10+policy+preferences&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=MNiNUqjsBoGjhge03oDgCg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=683) : Lots of people seem to have those settings, but just can't make them appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not show up if you do not have IE10 installed on the computer where you are editing the GPO from. You would think installing IE10/11 on a Windows 2008 R2 or Windows 7 would add the preferences but it does not. You actually need a Windows 8/8.1 + RSAT or Windows 2012/2012 R2 to see and manage IE10 (and 11 but you do not see 11) preferences.

Comment: FWIW, I also have a 2008R2 controller, with IE11 installed and options > IE8 still do not appear.

Comment: Hi, Adil. The 2008R2 DC Had IE10 installed, but I put IE11 on to try and solve this problem. Should that configuration have the settings? from what you're saying, that should be equivalent to Win7 + IE11 + RSAT?

Comment: It looks like you have to have a Windows 8 + RSAT or windows 2012 to be able to see and manage IE10/11 settings. I will update the answer as well.

Comment: I'll try that on Friday, and if it works, I'll flag as answered. wish that MS made that clearer in the documentation.

Comment: You hit the answer on the head Adil H: Even though you can see IE11/Win 8.x Administrative templates from 2008 R2, you can't see preferences (Or Windows 8 Security settings) from it. Using Win 8.1 Pro + RSAT sorted this out.Proxy policy isn't quote working, but just need to work through it now - the settings are there to work with, at least.