# internet explorer 10 gpo/gpp not letting me set intranet sites

Tags: group-policy

Domain has one 2003 server, the rest are 2008 r2.  boss wanted new image to include IE10.  IE10 not accepting old GPO using internet explorer maintenance.  Tried setting user preference policy but it won't let me add sites to the intranet (the sites box is greyed out).  Any way to get this to work?  I don't want to use the site injection feature because then users won't be able to add client sites to their sites lists.

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck using Internet Explorer Maintenance (IEM). It's not supported on IE10, the extension that processes the settings you are putting in via IEM is gone so they computers will not process the sites defined in IEM.

The only clue I can give you is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/01/04/how-to-add-trust-sites-into-ie-before-ie10-through-group-policy.aspx

None of the options are good in my opinion, but it is what we are left with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but here's Administrative Templates for IE10 on Windows Server 2003:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37009

Answer (score 0):

you need to have Windows 8 with RSAT or Windows Server 2012/R2 to edit the IE10 GPP. I think I saw this question elsewhere on ServerFault, I'll try and find it.

[**Here**](https://serverfault.com/a/557385/200767) is a similar situation to what you have.