# Internet Explorer 10 group policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, internet, internet-explorer

This question is related to [Internet Explorer 9 & 10 Group Policy Preferences missing](https://serverfault.com/questions/555996/internet-explorer-9-10-group-policy-preferences-missing)

I have about 20 domain controllers and when I try edit a group policy object then go to user configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Internet Settings then right click New > It only has IE 5,6,7,8 listed I have installed onto this domain controller IE 11 and restarted this particular dc.

Would I need to do this on all of the other DC before that setting would be available?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have IE11 installed on the computer where you are running Group Policy Management Console, managing IE11 group policy preferences do not work.  Your best option would be to use GPMC on a Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2 computer.

Note that installing IE11 should install updated template files to the PolicyDefinitions folder for you.  (You would need to copy the Central Store manually if you use that).

Administrative templates and Internet Explorer 11
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321438.aspx

"When you install Internet Explorer 11, it updates the local administrative files, Inetres.admx and Inetres.adml, both located in the PolicyDefinitions folder."

There are some additional policy settings that require updated templates (such as Enterprise Mode), but that should not affect the ability to use GPP.

How to configure Group Policy Preference settings for Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2898604

Here is an example GPO on 2012 R2:

[image]

And the same GPO when viewed on 2008 R2 with IE11, and the updated inetres.admx and inetres.adml files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get the full ADMX templates for Internet Explorer 11 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40905). Install them into your **SYSVOL\PolicyDefinitions** folder on any DC, replication should take care of the rest.

Edit:  One of the main differences for IE 11 is Enterprise Mode, which you will want to be prepared for. Other than that most settings will be the same.

Edit 2:  The install instructions at the download link cover troubleshooting the inetres.admx usage from GPMC in case the settings do not show up properly. They reference server 2003, not sure what OS you are running here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have done this but its still not showing up I have captured a screen shot of the settings im trying to get to.  [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/25iafwy.jpg